# Efficient sorting and aggregating data in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, aggregate

```
srch_destination     hotel_booked        count
28                   1                   4
28                   5                   1
28                   8                   2
28                   11                  9
28                   14                  17
19                   11                  3
19                   2                   5
19                   5                   8
19                   6                   10
```

Let's say I have a dataframe formatted above. These are searches, so let's say that 4 people who searched for destination 28 booked hotel 1. I essentially want to get a dataframe that contains a row for each search destination, along with the corresponding top 3 bookings. So for this dataframe, we would have two rows that look like:

```
srch_destination    top_hotels
28                  14 11 1
19                  6 5 2
```

Currently, my code is below where 'c_id' is the initial dataframe and 'a' is the desired output. I am coming from R and am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this sorting and subsequent aggregation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame()

for ind in np.unique(c_id.srch_destination):
    nlarg = c_id[c_id.srch_destination == ind].sort_values('count', ascending = False).head(3)['hotel_booked']    
    a = a.append({'srch_destination': ind, 'top_hotels': " ".join(map(str, nlarg))}, ignore_index=True)

a.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: Deleted my R answer...sorry..I missed that point. Mistakenly though you wanted python ported over to R.

Answer (score 3):

Use `nlargest` to get the top 3 based on the `count` column.

```
>>> (df.groupby('srch_destination')
       .apply(lambda group: group.nlargest(3, 'count').hotel_booked.tolist()))
srch_destination
19      [6, 5, 2]
28    [14, 11, 1]
dtype: object
```